# What motivation for assuming field K is infinite.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

A theorem in *Shaum's Outline of Linear Algebra* says that if we suppose the field $K$ is infinite then any system of linear equations has either a unique solution, or no solution, or an infinite number of solutions.

So if we have $n$ unknowns then solutions are vectors in $K^n$ which can be real or complex.

Why do we want $K$ to be infinite? Wouldn't any subset of $K$ still ensure the trichotomy i.e. we would still have either a unique solution, or no solution, or an infinite number of solutions?

Comment: If $K$ is finite there cannot be infinitely many solutions since there are only finitely many values in $K$ and finitely many values in $K^n$, namely $|K|^n$

Comment: I think I understand. The number of solutions would generally not be known because that number would be different for different systems of equations on a finite $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, if $K$ is a finite field, then $K^n$ has $|K|^n$ elements so there cannot be an infinite number of solutions.

The trichotomy then breaks up into $n+2$ cases. The linear system $Ax=b$ may have no solution - this occurs when $b \notin \mathrm{im}A$. On the other hand, if the solution set of $Ax=b$ is non-empty then it is a linear subspace of $K^n$. For every $d=0, 1, \dots, n$ it is possible that the solution set is $d$-dimensional and thus has $|K|^d$ elements.

Note that when $K$ is infinite, the above $n+2$ cases still appear, but the solution set is infinite for $d=1, \dots, n$.